# React Native - State doesn't change correctly on button press (TouchableHighlight)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i want to change a state after a button press on a touchableHighlight component. The problem is that the state doesn't update immediately, but it does after i press another one of the rendered components, and it adds the previous letter to the state. This is the code:

```
export default function App() {

  const [word, setword] = useState('');
  const handleChange=(e) => {
    setword(word.concat(e.target.outerText));
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.row}>
      {wordpuzzle.square[0].map((letter, index) => {
        return(
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.touchableHighlight} key={index} onPress={handleChange}>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{letter}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        )})
      }
```

This is the `wordpuzzle.json` file from where I'm mapping stuff to render inside components.

```
{
    "square": [
        ["P", "E", "R", "E"],
        ["I", "U", "B", "A"],
        ["T", "A", "B", "L"],
        ["E", "H", "C", "I"]
    ],
    "10": ["pubblicati"],
    "9": ["pubbliche", "pubblicai"],
    "8": ["pubblica"],
    "7": ["pubiche", "barbuta", "barbuti", "barbute"],
    "6": ["pubica", "rubati", "rubate"],
    "5": ["barbe", "beare"],
    "4": ["pere", "pera", "erba", "bali", "pube", "pubi", "bare",
        "taci", "aura", "aure", "ruba"
    ],
    "3": ["eta", "pia", "pie", "che", "ali", "bea"]
}
```

Comment: What I see is that the component has word in its state but renders wordpuzzle. But how are the two related? Shouldn't you post more code to reveal that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might try using previous value in setting state based on previous state

```
setword(prev => prev.concat(e.target.outerText));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it!

```
setword([...word.concat(e.target.outerText)]);
```

Word state is char array.
when you call setWord, word content would be added but word variable address itself doesn't change, the system doesn't recognize state changing so UI component doesn't refresh.
Basically you should call setWord with a new array.

Comment: `concat()` returns new string, does not modify existing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat